# homework:Bankers Algorithm,read matrix txt file

Tags: readfile, bankers-algorithm

Bankers algorithm: I am trying to read from txt file into 4 variables. allocation,Max matrix/ available and request vectors. i am stuck as to how to read it properly. The txt file first value is number of process and 2nd value is resources, the first matrix is allocation and 2nd matrix is Max, then lastly 2 vectors.this is what i have so far

this is the txt file:

5

4

0 0 1 2
1 0 0 0
1 3 5 4
0 6 3 2
0 0 1 4

0 0 1 2
1 7 5 0
2 3 5 6
0 6 5 2
0 6 5 6

1 5 2 0

1:0 4 2 0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
ifstream mFile;
mFile.open("s1.txt");
vector<int> request[],available[];
int allocation[][],Max[][];
int m,n;
vector <int> work,finish;
work = available;

mFile >>m >>n;
while(!mFile.eof())
{

for(int i=0; i< m; i++)
{
for(int j =0;j<n;j++)
{
    mFile >> allocation[i][i];
    mFile >> Max[i][j];
    request[i][j] = Max[i][j] - allocation[i][j];

}
} 
}   


mFile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where to start: without searching too far I can see:

`vector<int> need[][],available[];`

What is need?, a 2D array of int vectors with 0 size ?

You use variable `m` and `n`, but I don't see them defined or declared.

Comment: right i made some edits. i am having trouble has to how i can read that txt file into the variables i have declared

Comment: You still aren't actually allocating any memory for `allocation` or `Max`. BTW: stick to one variable naming convention. All should start with lower case. Have you even tried to compile this? what is `need`?